# derivative of inseparable equation

Tags: derivatives

Is there a way to find the derivative of an equation where I cannot separate the independent variable from the dependent variable. For example, what is $dy/dx$ given

\begin{equation*}
\cos(y) = \dfrac{x}{x+y}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Use implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Try implicit differentiation, that is, differentiating the whole thing with respect to $x$ so for example $$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(y))=-\sin(y) \frac{dy}{dx}$$
Then, after you take the derivative of both sides you can you can solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.